# MySQL return null for non-existent record

Tags: mysql, database, select, join, union

I have 2 MySQL tables, which I am required to join and access as a derived table.

Basic example with some dummy rows:

```
CREATE DATABASE Test;
USE Test;

CREATE TABLE TableOne(
    Id INT auto_increment NOT NULL,
    SomeField FLOAT,
    Timestamp DATETIME,
        PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE TableTwo(
    Id INT auto_increment NOT NULL,
    SomeField FLOAT,
    Timestamp DATETIME,
        PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

INSERT INTO TableOne
    (Timestamp, SomeField)
VALUES
    ('2017-06-30 23:30:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-06-30 23:45:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:00:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:15:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:30:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:45:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 01:00:00', RAND()),    
    ('2017-07-01 01:15:00', RAND()),    
    ('2017-07-01 01:30:00', RAND());    


INSERT INTO TableTwo
    (Timestamp, SomeField)
VALUES
    ('2017-06-30 23:30:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-06-30 23:40:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-06-30 23:50:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:00:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:10:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:20:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:30:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:40:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 00:50:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 01:00:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 01:10:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 01:20:00', RAND()),
    ('2017-07-01 01:30:00', RAND());
```

And to read the tables, I am using:

```
SELECT
    SomeField,
    Timestamp
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SomeField,
            Timestamp
        FROM
            TableOne

        UNION

        SELECT
            SomeField,
            Timestamp
        FROM
            TableTwo    
    ) d1
WHERE
    d1.Timestamp BETWEEN '2017-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-01 01:00:00'
ORDER BY
    d1.Timestamp;
```

This query returns the following table:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| SomeField  | Timestamp           |
+------------+---------------------+
|   0.380433 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00 |
| 0.00938889 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00 |
|   0.963191 | 2017-07-01 00:10:00 |
|   0.290852 | 2017-07-01 00:15:00 |
|   0.674658 | 2017-07-01 00:20:00 |
|   0.483715 | 2017-07-01 00:30:00 |
|   0.426091 | 2017-07-01 00:30:00 |
|   0.394602 | 2017-07-01 00:40:00 |
|   0.257901 | 2017-07-01 00:45:00 |
|   0.521865 | 2017-07-01 00:50:00 |
|   0.425519 | 2017-07-01 01:00:00 |
|  0.0112322 | 2017-07-01 01:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Timestamp in Test.TableOne are (for the example) every fifteen minutes.

Timestamp in Test.TableTwo are (for the example) every ten minutes.

What I want to be able to do, is return the derived table with **all** timestamps with the 'SomeField' column displaying Null for the the corresponding DATETIME.

An example (using the tables above) would be would look like:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| SomeField  | Timestamp           |
+------------+---------------------+
|   0.380433 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00 |
| 0.00938889 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00 |
|   0.963191 | 2017-07-01 00:10:00 |
|   NULL     | 2017-07-01 00:10:00 |
|   0.290852 | 2017-07-01 00:15:00 |
|   NULL     | 2017-07-01 00:15:00 |
|   0.674658 | 2017-07-01 00:20:00 |
|   NULL     | 2017-07-01 00:20:00 |
|   0.483715 | 2017-07-01 00:30:00 |
|   0.426091 | 2017-07-01 00:30:00 |
|   0.394602 | 2017-07-01 00:40:00 |
|   NULL     | 2017-07-01 00:40:00 |
|   0.257901 | 2017-07-01 00:45:00 |
|   NULL     | 2017-07-01 00:45:00 |
|   0.521865 | 2017-07-01 00:50:00 |
|   NULL     | 2017-07-01 00:50:00 |
|   0.425519 | 2017-07-01 01:00:00 |
|  0.0112322 | 2017-07-01 01:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have tried a number of different JOINs to achieve this with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you had just one row by timestamp and two colums with both values from tableone and tabletwo would it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a smaller query if you used just one row by timestamp and two colums with values from each table.

However, if you really need the output just like you asked, you need to emulate two full outer join and unite them:

```
select * from (
           select t1.SomeField,Timestamp from TableOne t1 left join TableTwo t2 using (Timestamp) union all 
           select t2.SomeField,Timestamp from TableOne t1 left join TableTwo t2 using (Timestamp) union all
           select t1.SomeField,Timestamp from TableOne t1 right join TableTwo t2 using (Timestamp) union all 
           select t2.SomeField,Timestamp from TableOne t1 right join TableTwo t2 using (Timestamp)

          ) tt where tt.Timestamp BETWEEN '2017-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-01 01:00:00' order by Timestamp
```